# What is usage of angular.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular js.from this site https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap it is saying Use this function to manually start up angular application.

```
<html>
<body>
<div ng-controller="WelcomeController">
  {{greeting}}
</div>

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('WelcomeController', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Welcome!';
  });
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what is the meaning of this line angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']); ?

the above program just create a module and controller but it use `bootstrap`.......`without bootstrap controller can not be instantiated ?`.

looking for guidance. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.bootstrap` is used as an alternative approach to initializing your application without using `ng-app`. In the above example, you can see that there is no `ng-app` directive added anywhere in the document. Therefore, using `angular.bootstrap` you defined the app module to be associated with the document which is `demo` in the above example.

You can also define the modules to be used with any element that can be identified by using `document.getElementById()` function in the first parameter of `angular.bootstrap`.

**Using angular.bootstrap**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="mycontainer" ng-controller="WelcomeController">
   {{greeting}}
</div>

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('WelcomeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Welcome!';
});
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('mycontainer'), ['demo']);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('mycontainer'), ['demo']);` this code try to associate demo module with div having class name `mycontainer` ?

Comment: i am pretty new in angular. so like to know when people follow this kind of code means use bootstrap function without ng-app. when people avoiding ng-app directive?

Answer (score 0):

For running multiple apps in an HTML document you need to manually bootstrap them using `angular.bootstrap`

Comment: r u trying to say when we work with multiple module in same page then we need to instantiate them manually?

Comment: @Mou yes only one is instantiated by angular  for rest you need to do it manually

Comment: not clear what you try to say. would you please elaborate it. thanks